# python boto issue with displaying latest snapshot for each instance

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, boto

I am trying to print Instance name, volume id , instance ID, instance private IP, snapshot start time snapshot ID in one tabular form.

Code :-

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import boto.ec2
import time
import datetime

conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("eu-west-1")
reservations = conn.get_all_instances()
tags = conn.get_all_tags()
snapshots = conn.get_all_snapshots(owner="self")
instances = [i for r in reservations for i in r.instances]

import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.today()
one_day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
yesterday = today - one_day

from datetime import datetime

for inst in instances:
    for snap in snapshots:
            start_time = datetime.strptime (snap.start_time.split('.')[0],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
            if start_time > yesterday and 'Name' in inst.tags:
                    print "%s (%s) (%s) (%s) [%s] " % (inst.tags['Name'], start_time, snap.volume_id
```

It's looping through all instances again & again. E.g-> I have 17 instances then it loops through all instances 17*17 times and displays the result.

Any suggestions..

Comment: You have a bug in your algorithm it seems. Can you update the question with more details on how you tried to debug and solve the problem ?

Comment: Snapshots are not related to an instance (they are taken from a volume-id) without extra work, e.g. tags. So you will need to ensure snapshots have some tag that allows you to relate it to an instance id, e.g. name or id and then only display the snapshots that satisfy that condition (e.g. inst.tags['name'] == snapshot.tags['name'].

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your snapshots don't come from your instances so you could use something like this

```
for inst, snap in zip(instances, snapshots):
    do stuff
```

That way it will loop through both at the same time and not all of your snapshots per instance